# How to migrate/upgrade to sitecore 7 from version 6.5/6.6

Tags: windows, sitecore, sitecore7

Can you please provide tips/roadmap of migration from Sitecore 6.5/6.6 instances to 7 version.

I'd also like to know any impacts to existing system. Does anyone know about any issues?

Answer (score 2):

You can find everything here about upgrading : 
https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/Update/7_0_rev_130424.aspx

Here also you can find good tips :

http://www.partechit.nl/nl/blog/2013/05/upgrading-our-website-to-sitecore-7

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the upgrade is super easy and there are very few breaking changes.  Almost all of the breaking changes are due to the updated version of the Lucene.Net version.  Also, the fact that it requires .net 4.5 may be a consideration for your solution.  Otherwise, it's pretty much just new assemblies added on top of what was already there.

Note that if you are on 6.5 or lower, you will have to first upgrade to 6.6 and then 7.